# Cannot edit polygon collider in unity-editor while Zooming In.

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to edit polygon Collider in unity 5.4.0. when I zooming in the scene view and trying to edit polygon collider it's not allowing me to edit.please help me to solve this problem. it's really annoying.

Comment: Please explain how it isn't working. It works fine for me. (5.5)

Comment: when I am in Zooming in mode for scene view and click on edit collider from Inspector and there should be green area indicating your polygon area including highlighted nodes for the polygon shape should come.but here i cannot see that green line.

Comment: Not entirely sure what "Zooming in mode". Are you doing smething different from this? http://imgur.com/a/efOzb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're experiencing the same bug i ran across a few days ago.  I fixed it by resetting the layout to factory settings. Everything worked after that, I hope this works for you..